# Site traffic -> new users -> an influx of invalid spam flags

Tags: discussion, flagging

I just wanted to post this as a featured item to let everyone know that we have a lot more traffic than normal which means a lot of new users.

I want to thank everyone who is adding constructive comments and downvotes to the inevitable influx of poor quality posts.

I would encourage people to avoid using spam flags for posts that have zero constructive comments, zero down votes and are not actually commercial promotions or offensive speech.

Furthermore, we're declining more than the usual flags for the **not an answer** reason when the post is clearly an attempt to answer (it's not a me too, or an entirely new question) and it's in some way not the answer an expert might give or it even is a totally wrong answer.

Please try to be patient with new users. Assume they are here to learn and contrite and perhaps use the other flag to explain precisely what you feel is harmful to the site by leaving the post up. We can mark those flags as helpful much easier than if we ding a new account for spam just because they posted a wrong answer. Also, it saves the system from de-prioritizing your future flags since an accumulation of several declined flags puts your input at the bottom of the list.

The majority of the flags are awesome and the vast majority merited some flag - just that severe flags are being used for trivial posts that a simple edit or a helpful comment and some patience will clear up.

Comment: +1, but I think we ought to clarify what *should* be considered spam. "New user" is often a costume.  See http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/could-we-set-out-objective-criteria-for-what-is-spam-or-commercial-promotion

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Your spam flags have been spot on and I don't recall rejecting any. We do sometimes let a single post remain for a while to give a user a chance to distinguish themselves from a spam bot account - but the down votes on those posts helps immensely.

Comment: Heh.  I think you're technically right -- my rejected recent flags were my incorrect use of "not an answer."  Anyway, let's call a spam flag marked as helpful but ultimately ineffective (the answer living on) a "soft rejection" -- and I've seen a handful of *those* ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**42**

<sub>(unanswered questions get bumped back to the top later when we least expect it, so to prevent this from happening, I've posted an "answer" to this "question." The question is indeed a timely reminder and a useful use of the [featured](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag. Besides, you can't go wrong with the answer 42.)</sub>

Comment: Nicely done. 42 is the answer after all.

Comment: I wonder if we can flip this around and have a better answer by editing the question down to what we saw and leave the guidance in addition to 42.